# DOING A SUM USING GROUPBY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have the below data where the products A, B, C and D are the components of the BundleID 'ABCD'. I am doing a sum of the price doing a groupby BundleID. The issue here is that I want it to throw an error and not do the sum in case a product price is 0. Can someone please suggest a way out here.

Can we replace 0's evrywhere with some dummy value so as to throw an error while doing the sum?

```
BundleID    Product  Price
ABCD        A         5
ABCD        B         10
ABCD        C         0
ABCD        D         20
EFGH        E         50
EFGH        F         100
EFGH        G         50
EFGH        H         10


WITH BUNDLE_SUM AS (
select S.BundleID,
        SUM(CONVERT(float,LV.VALUE_0)) AS BUNDLE_SUM 
        from PM_SCOPE S
        JOIN PM_LOOKUP_VALUE LV ON LV.SCOPE_ID = S.SCOPE_ID
        WHERE LD.LOOkUP_NAME = 'Bundle Details'
        GROUP BY S.BundleID
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: why not just exclude those with `price is 0` ?

Comment: Why dont you add another condition to the where clause such as WHERE <your_condition> AND LD.Price > 0 ?

Comment: is LV.VALUE_0 same price field defined in your sample data? what is datatype of your price column?

Comment: LV.VALUE_0 is actually the price column.

Comment: Squirrel - Idea is to have the bundle sum only when all the components of the bundle have a price. If one price is missing (meaning its 0), then the bundle sum we get is incorrect.

Comment: I also asked what is datatype of your price column?

Comment: @Newbie Answer is updated.

Comment: Data type of price column is nvarchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi just check existence of zero in the table if yes raise error else do group or what ever you want to do.. ie

```
   select S.BundleID,
        SUM(CONVERT(float,LV.VALUE_0)) AS BUNDLE_SUM 
        from PM_SCOPE S
        JOIN PM_LOOKUP_VALUE LV ON LV.SCOPE_ID = S.SCOPE_ID
        WHERE LD.LOOkUP_NAME = 'Bundle Details' and 
               s BundleID not in (select distinct BundleID from PM_SCOPE S
             JOIN PM_LOOKUP_VALUE LV ON LV.SCOPE_ID = S.SCOPE_ID and LV.VALUE_0=0   )
        GROUP BY S.BundleID
```

Comment: I want my query to somehow not calculate the whole bundle price even if only one product is missing price. So in my example above, the price of C is 0, so the price for bundleID ABCD should not be calculated, however it should do fine for the bundleID EFGH.

Comment: I tried doing the following but it gives an error for the whole query.

Comment: sandeep rawat - Thanks Sandeep. I havent tested this completely but i have a feeling this will work.

Comment: Hi Sandeep - need a help from you again. Theres a small issue with this one. I realised that I also need to do a groupby COUNTRYID also. so in that case if I use the same query, its going to exclude all the bundleID for all the countries even if theres only any one component having a price 0 for any one of them. Can you please help suggest something. Thanks

Comment: please share full scenario what exactly you need i will respond. i am not able to understand where u need to do group by a and plz share table structure ...here or vi mail.

Comment: Hi Sandeep- I'll drop you an email. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select bundleid,
sum(Case when price=0 then 'string' else price end)
from
your table
group by bundleid
```

idea is `string` +`int` conversion will fail,if your price is int..

Answer (score 0):

You can as the below:

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (BundleID NVARCHAR(10), Price FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @Tbl
VALUES
('ABCD', 5  ),
('ABCD', 10 ),
('ABCD', 0  ),
('ABCD', 20 ),
('EFGH', 50 ),
('EFGH', 100),
('EFGH', 50 ),
('EFGH', 10  )


SELECT 
    BundleID,
    IIF(MIN(Price) = 0, 'INCORRECT', CAST(SUM(Price) AS NVARCHAR(10))) TotalPrice
FROM 
    @Tbl
GROUP BY
    BundleID
```

Result:

```
BundleID    TotalPrice
ABCD        INCORRECT
EFGH        210
```